# ogr2ogr SHP to MSSQL import leaves geometry column empty

Tags: qgis, gdal, shapefile, ogr, ogr2ogr

I am trying to import a Shapefile with polygon features into MSSQL database with this command:

```
ogr2ogr -f "MSSQLSpatial" "MSSQL:server=***;uid=***;pwd=***;database=***" "D:\GeoData\processed\usage_land.shp" -a_srs "EPSG:4326" -nlt "POLYGON" -nln "import_usage" -progress -skipfailures
```

Import does work so far but the geometry column *ogr_geometry* stays NULL.
Any ideas how to get this feature working? Which command am I missing?

Comment: what does `ogrinfo` say about the shapefile - most likely issue is multipolygon to polygon column

Comment: Polygon - tried other geometry types in -nlt command as well (geometry, multipolygon)

Comment: do you end up with a geometry column called `the_geom`?

Comment: No, its `ogr_geometry` initially, but I added `-lco "GEOMETRY_NAME=geometry"` for my purpose

Comment: I would try without `--skipfailures` and see if there is an error

Answer (score 3):

Similar symptoms, but I had to add `--config MSSQLSPATIAL_USE_BCP NO` to my ogr2ogr instruction. I think a consequence of this parameter is that the ogr2ogr process runs slower than it could under ideal circumstances.

Of note: I installed GDAL using the OSGEO installer, which for some reason didn't include anything in the `gdalplugins` folder. Meanwhile, that 'USE BCP' parameter is true/yes by default, and it seems to need something from the plugins folder. Hopefully this will help someone.

Comment: Ogr2ogr stopped working for me when I updated to 3.3.1. It created the Table in MSSQL but imported no rows and reported no error.
Adding --config MSSQLSPATIAL_USE_BCP NO fixed the issue.
But I have no idea why....

Comment: 1/2 @steloe, do you have anything in your `gdalplugins` directory? I'm curious how you installed GDAL. I don't usually use the OSGEO installer. But in this case I did because it was a Windows system (which makes sense considering I was using it for MSSQL activity). Anyway it seems a byproduct of *the way I used* the OSGEO installer was that I didn't get the plugins, which might include something necessary to support the default `--config MSSQLSPATIAL_USE_BCP NO` option.

Comment: 2/2 I suspect that--had I anticipated this scenario--I probably could have made different selections when running the OSGEO installer to make sure I got the `gdalplugins` I needed. I'm not sure if there is a standard set of plugins, or if they need to be deliberately selected one at a time. I forget where I learned this, but that `USE_BCP` seems to depend on some sidecar library that GDAL ropes-in when necessary, and (if I understand this correctly), the absence of this library breaks the default option. The default should arguably not require the external lib, but that's another convo. :)

Comment: Ah. Ok, I think it's `ogr_MSSQLSpatial.dll`. [See here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/408384/4968).

Comment: Oh, interesting. I have to admit, I diddn't dive that deep into the gdal internals... I used the osgeo installer, advanced setup and chose Qgis 3.20 and some minor tools. My gdalplugins directory ist empty.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I found the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52259696/ogr2ogr-does-not-create-tables

I was missing the `-lco UPLOAD_GEOM_FORMAT=wkt` and this seemed to do the job!