# ogrinfo doesn't respond while exporting to MSSQL with ogr2ogr

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr, ogrinfo

I am trying to export data from postgres to MSSQL.
While

`ogr2ogr -nln outputLayerName  -f "MSSQLSpatial" "MSSQL_conn_string" --config MSSQLSPATIAL_USE_GEOMETRY_COLUMNS NO "postgres_conn_string" input_table_name -overwrite -progress`

is executing, I tried to do `ogrinfo` or pythons `ogr.Open()` on MSSQL_conn_string, but both stay in pending status as long as ogr2ogr is executing. Does anyone had similar problem ? The reason why I'm doing this is catching number of imported features while ogr2ogr is running.

Comment: I am rather sure that your issue is driver specific and affects MSSQL but not all GDAL vector drivers. Perhaps you could edit the title to emphasize that.

Answer (score 0):

@Goran, I've had mixed experiences using ogr2ogr to import into MSSQL. Out of curiosity, you might try adding this to your command just to see what happens:

`--config MSSQLSPATIAL_USE_BCP NO`

See [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/404866/4968) and the question it's posted on for a little more detail. Of note‒I recommend trying this option even if you don't think it's relevant!